# String modification/filtering in MS SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Below is the input string:

Declare @inputvalue varchar(max)

Set @inputvalue = '**Brussels sprout** is one type of green veggie you should simply steam away without a doubt. Steaming your ***sprout*** will only enable a build up on your immunity.
 Raw  **Sproutbrussels** or ***Brussels*** still has the cholesterol-lowering ability but as much as steamed **brussels           sprout**. Likewise, here are some of the other health benefits of steaming **brusselssprout** ".
I like ***sprout***, not ***Brussels*.**

**Requirement:**

Need to remove words sprout and Brussels if they are not adjacent to each other i.e.

1) Need to remove word "sprout" if "Brussels" is not present adjacent to it (left or right,with or without       space)
 2) Need to remove word "Brussels" if "sprout" is not present adjacent to it (left or right,with or without        space)
 3)  The words are to be considered adjacent even if there are multiple spaces in between them. 
      **Brussels           sprout**  - This should not be removed from the string.
      **Brusselssprout**             - This should not be removed from the string.
      **Sproutbrussels**             - This should not be removed from the string.

The words highlighted in ***Bold Italics*** are to be removed and the words highlighted in **Bold**  are not to be removed.

Note: The whole input string can be different/may contain no space at all between words.Thus it can't be done by splitting with space or any other delimiter.

**Expected output string:**

"**Brussels sprout** is one type of green veggie you should simply steam away without a doubt. Steaming your will only enable a build up on your immunity. Raw **Sproutbrussels** or  still has the cholesterol-lowering ability but as much as steamed **brussels           sprout**. Likewise, here are some of the other health benefits of steaming **brusselssprout**".
I like , not"

Comment: You could write a CLR script that employs REGEX, if you want to be slick about it.   Otherwise iterate through the string with PATINDEX and analyze the characters before and after each occurrence of the two target words.

Comment: CLR script is not possible for me and yes, iterating is the last option that i will choose.

Comment: Just a comment on the Note in the question. Split the words on space delimiter should not be a problem since you are only looking for the words `brussels` or `sprout`, and remove the ones that do not have the required word next to it. The `Brusselssprout` or `Sproutburssels` are different words that should not be checked naturally.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very efficeint but it works:

```
Declare @inputvalue varchar(max)

Set @inputvalue = 'Brussels sprout is one type of green veggie you should simply steam away without a doubt. Steaming your sprout will only enable a build up on your immunity. Raw Sproutbrussels or Brussels still has the cholesterol-lowering ability but as much as steamed brussels           sprout. Likewise, here are some of the other health benefits of steaming brusselssprout ".
I like sprout, not Brussels.';

declare @word1 nvarchar(100) = 'brussels';
declare @word2 nvarchar(100) = 'sprout ';

with W1(id, pos, val) as (
    Select 1, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(@inputvalue, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1)-1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
            or left(ltrim(right(@inputvalue, len(@inputvalue) - CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1) - len(@word1) +1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
        then @inputvalue else 
            left(@inputvalue, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1) - 1)
        end
    Union All
    Select id+1, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(val, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos)-1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
            or left(ltrim(right(val, len(val) - CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) - len(@word1) +1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
        then val else 
            left(val, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) - 1)
            + right(val, len(val) - len(@word1) - CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) + 1) 
        end
    From w1     
    Where CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) > 0
), W2(id, pos, val) as (
    Select 1, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, 1)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(val, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, 1)-1)), len(@word1)) = @word1 
            or left(ltrim(right(val, len(val) - CHARINDEX(@word2, val, 1) - len(@word2) +1)), len(@word1)) = @word1 
        then val else 
            left(val, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, 1) - 1)
        end
    From ( 
        Select val From w1 Where id in (Select max(id) From w1)
    ) as w
    Union All
    Select id+1, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(val, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos)-1)), len(@word1)) = @word1 
            or left(ltrim(right(val, len(val) - CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos) - len(@word2) +1)), len(@word1)) = @word1 
        then val else 
            left(val, CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos) - 1)
            + right(val, len(val) - len(@word2) - CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos) + 1) 
        end
    From w2 
    Where CHARINDEX(@word2, val, pos) > 0
)
Select val From w2 Where id in (Select max(id) From w2)

Option (maxrecursion 0)
```

CTE W1 could also be put in a function:

```
with W1(id, pos, val) as (
    Select 1, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(@inputvalue, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1)-1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
            or left(ltrim(right(@inputvalue, len(@inputvalue) - CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1) - len(@word1) +1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
        then @inputvalue else 
            left(@inputvalue, CHARINDEX(@word1, @inputvalue, 1) - 1)
        end
    Union All
    Select id+1, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos)+1, 
        Case When
            right(rtrim(left(val, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos)-1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
            or left(ltrim(right(val, len(val) - CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) - len(@word1) +1)), len(@word2)) = @word2 
        then val else 
            left(val, CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) - 1)
            + right(val, len(val) - len(@word1) - CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) + 1) 
        end
    From w1     
    Where CHARINDEX(@word1, val, pos) > 0
)
Select val From w1 Where id in (Select max(id) From w1)
```

And then you only have call it twice:

```
Set @newvalue = replaceWords(replaceWords(@inputvalue, 'brussels', 'sprout'), 'sprout', 'brussels')
```

Note that I love Brussel sprouts!!! :)